# I am getting error- 'Failed to install-write all apks'

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I am working on android studio project and after completing the code i run the on my android device and it showed an error-
***Failed to install-
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
List of apks:
[0] 'app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to install-write all apks'***

It was working fine as I have tested the app many times but now it is showing error. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

This error generally occurs when device doesn't have sufficiant storage space to install the apk.
Check your phone storage, clean some memory to make sure you have enough memory to fully install/run your application

Comment: the message 'Failed to install-write all apks' is not caused for a lack of space.

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because of less memory on the emulator device
how to solve it :-

1. Go to device manager
2. Click on emulator setting(The pen symbol)
3. Then click on advance settings
4. Increase the internal memory of the device to at least 2Gb

The problem should be resolved .

Comment: I am not using the emulator and I get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Check versionNameSuffix of productFlavors and buildTypes in build.gradle (:app) for each installation of build variant will be unique

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error

> Installation failed due to: 'Failed to install-write all apks'

in a real device:

> 'Failed to install-write all apks'

**You have to restart your device, and you will be able to upload your app.**